# passportjs, mocha, supertest ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, passport.js, supertest

I am trying to test authentication with mocha, supertest, and passport but I am getting connection refused error. I assume it has to do with the way I am starting my app...

```
var testUser = {
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "test"
};

var app = require('../../server');

var request = require('superagent');
var user = request.agent(app);

describe('authentication api ', function() {

    it('should login a user', function(done) {
        user.post('/login')
            .send(testUser)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if(err) throw err;
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

This user does exist in my mongo database. Within my server file which is two levels higher:

```
module.exports = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('app listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

Comment: setting different port for test environment helped me

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed in March of 2015. The yeoman Dafmonk Angular Fullstack generator still uses an older version of supertest. I fixed this by opening my `package.json` file and updating the supertest version from "~0.11.0" to "1.0.1". Then I ran: `npm prune && npm install` The ECONNREFUSED went away.

Check out this bug and the commit at the very end: https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/314